# Unable to access the database in the remote server from my binary

Tags: c++

if my binary is launched from the command Line(in windows 7) it is able to access the database of a remote server but if the same binary is launched by a another binary which is a service made by me it is not able to access that database.

My service is running as Local System. When i tried to change the command line to SYSTEM user then also my binary was able to access to database of the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Your process most likely fails because it is launched from a different user context. A process  inherits the user context of its parent process (the one that launches it). That's why it succeeds when launched from the command line, but fails when launched from your service. Your service probably runs under a different (and more limited) user account from cmd.exe.